# Practice on Simple Tracing With Classes

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

I am currently working on a practice test for an exam. I have a question to why the output is what it is.

Here is the code:

```
class Number
{
private:
    int *v;
public:
    Number(int *addr)
    {
        v = new int;
        *v = *addr;
        cout << *v << "   ";
    }
    int *getV() { return v;}
    void setV(int num) {*v = num;}
    ~Number()
    {
        cout << *v << "   ";
    }
};
```

====

```
void increaseNumber1(Number p);
void increaseNumber2(Number &p);

int main()
{
    int num1 = 5, num2 = 6, *ptr;
    ptr = new int;

    Number p(&num1);
    Number q(&num2);
    Number r(ptr);
    r.setV(11);
    increaseNumber1(p); 
    increaseNumber2(q); 

    delete q.getV();
    return 0;
}
void increaseNumber1(Number p)
{
    int i = *(p.getV());
    i = i + 10;
    p.setV(i);
}
void increaseNumber2(Number &p)
{
    int i = *(p.getV());
    i = i + 10;
    p.setV(i);
}
```

The output is suppose to be: `5   6   garbage  15   11   garbage  15`

Here is my thought process. First, we make a Number object 'p'. This sets its Number *v value to 5. So it prints 5. Okay so far.

Second, we make a Number object 'q'. This sets its Number *v value to 6 and prints out 6. Okay so far.

Then creates a Number object 'r', but it is a pointer with garbage value since it just holds address that was allocated. So it prints a "garbage" value. Okay so far.

Now I am stuck to why a 15 is printed. When calling increaseNumber1(p);, it passes in the Number p object. Updates *v to 15 since 5 + 10. And now p object has *v equal to 15. Nothing should print, correct?

Then increaseNumber2(q); is called. But we pass in the address. What is the difference between this parameter and the prior function call? Anyways, should this update q to 16.

Then delete q.getV() function. We no longer have access to the private field.

return 0.

Now the stack calls remove the objects, thus destructors called. So printing 11, garbage, 15.

So what I believe to be is `5   6   garbage   11   garbage  15`

not

```
5   6   garbage  15   11   garbage  15
```

Anyone able to help me out and point out where my thinking is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And now p object has *v equal to 15. Nothing should print, correct?

Arguments are passed into `increaseNumber1` by value. This means (in layman's terms) a copy of `p` is created and `increaseNumber1` operates on this copy. At the end of the function, the copy is destroyed, calling the destructor which prints `15`.

> Then increaseNumber2(q); is called. But we pass in the address. What is the difference between this parameter and the prior function call?

The argument is not copied into the function. `increaseNumber2` operates on the `q` from the caller. Therefore, it is not destroyed at the end of the function and nothing is printed.

> Anyways, should this update q to 16.

Yes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have a question. What differentiates the two methods? How can I tell if one is copied or not into the function?

Comment: The & in the argument list indicates that this argument is passed by reference (i.e. the object of the caller is used instead of a copy).